# $|p(z)|=1$ contains no circles

Tags: complex-analysis

Help with the following problem would be appreciated:

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ with at least two distinct roots. Prove that no connected component of the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |p(z)|=1\}$ is a circle.